# Why is this regex with a capture group not working in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I do this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function getVersion {
  REGEX="^$2-(.*?)\.ear$"
  if [[ "$1" =~ $REGEX ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    echo "Cannot deduce artifact version from file name $1, exiting" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

MY_APP=app-1.3.4.ear
APP_VERSION=$(getVersion "$MY_APP" app)
echo "Version is $APP_VERSION"
```

I would expect `getVersion` to return `1.3.4`, but it produces the error message instead. Why doesn't the regex match?

Comment: You can't use `?` in bash to do a non-greedy match.

Comment: bash do not supports non-greedy match using `.*?`

Comment: pcregrep command supports non-greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't support `?` to mean *non-greedy* in a regular expression.

Luckily, you don't need it in this case:

```
function getVersion {
  REGEX="^$2-(.*)\.ear$"
  if [[ "$1" =~ $REGEX ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    echo "Cannot deduce artifact version from file name $1, exiting" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

The fact that you're specifying what must come after the version number prevents it from being consumed by the `.*`.

As an aside, I'd recommend getting out of the habit of using uppercase variable names in the shell; they're used internally so you run the risk of accidentally overwriting something useful.

I'd also normally advise against using the bash-specific `function` syntax in favour of the standard `getVersion() {` but you're using bash features so I guess it's not so much of an issue.